# Clip, then stroke a UIBezierPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I want to stroke the edges of a UIBezierPath that are clipped by the current window.  I already stroke the path, but it extends beyond the window.  In the simplified illustration here you can see the result is that there are two unstroked edges in the lower right and bottom.

Here is what I am doing currently in a UILabel subclass:

```
[myPath addClip];
[myPath stroke];
```

[image]

TIA

Comment: Its a little unclear what your asking here. If you are attempting and want to draw a path that is outside your window, your view/window needs configured to not clip.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I want to add a stroke to the blue shape where it meets the edge of the window.